# Testing against multiple versions with Maven

Tags: maven

I'm maintaining an open source project, that defines following dependency (using a version range)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.xtend.lib</artifactId>
    <version>[2.6.0, 2.8.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

Issuing `mvn clean install` works perfectly, using the latest version of the `org.eclipse.xtend.lib` allowed by the range. But I would like to also make sure, that my product works with other versions from the range, say with 2.6.0.

My question is: How can I force Maven to use some specified version of a dependency without changing my pom.xml?

I though, it could be something like this:

```
for version in  2.6.0  2.6.1  2.7.0  2.7.1  ; do
  # NOT WORKING!!!
  mvn clean install -Denforce_version_org.eclipse.xtend_org.eclipse.xtend.lib=$version
done
```

Comment: Why are you using a version range in the first place? You could factor this into a property and override it from the command line.

Comment: Yes, overwriting a property should do the trick. Thank you!